# Checking divisor checking in Array using streams

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I would like to find out if it is possible to execute the below nested for loop checking each element in a list and the count of its divisors not equal to 1 from that same list, as a Stream. If so, would it be recommended over a conventional for loop?

Sample Input - "List keys" converted to an "Array - arr".

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++){
    int count = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < keys.size(); k++){
        if(arr[i] % arr[k] == 0 && arr[k] != 1){
            count++;
        }
    }
    max = Math.max(max,count);
}
```

Comment: Sample inputs (`keys` and `arr`) and expected outputs would help a lot. I cannot imagine the logic behind.

Comment: "recommended over a conventional for loop": according to which aspect? Readability, performance, code complexity, aestethic beauty, testability, ease of debugging?

Comment: Apologies Nikolas, I have added the sample inputs.

Comment: In terms of performance, would this be preferred? - Ralf Kleberhoff

Comment: Is `keys.size()` equal to `arr.length`?

Comment: @Webbo: No worries :) The sample input means *both* the instances type *and* the data itself (ex. `List<Integer> keys = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);`). Remember the output as well (say `int max` should be `4` and explain why). Why is it important ? We need to be 100 % how the code works, how to test it and find a way to rewrite to Stream API and give you the best answer comparing both ways, recommending one and explaining why. So please, **provide the additional information** as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `streams` like below, but as @Ralf Kleberhoff mentioned advantages of `streams` over a conventional `for-loop` depends on various factors, readability wise it is concise, but for debugging or logging I think conventional `for-loop`'s are better

```
int max = keys.stream()
          .map(i -> IntStream.range(0, keys.size()).filter(k -> arr[i] % arr[k] == 0 && arr[k] != 1).count())
          .max((o1, o2) -> Math.toIntExact(o1 - o2))
          .map(Math::toIntExact).orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: As rajan mentioning the loop version is more readable, you can improve by extracting a method out of k -> arr[i] % arr[k] == 0 && arr[k] != 1)

Answer (score 0):

The relation between `keys` list and array `arr` is not quite clear.

In the original code the loops are based on iteration by the size of the `keys` list (the contents of `keys` is ignored).

Also, it may be needed to exclude `0` in denominator, and when a number is divided by itself.

The `for-loops` with indexes may be replaced with `IntStream.range(0, keys.size())`:

```java
int[] divisors = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .map(i -> (int) IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                .filter(k -> arr[i] != arr[k] && arr[k] != 0 && arr[k] != 1 && arr[i] % arr[k] == 0)
                .count()
        )
        .toArray();
```

Instead, `Arrays.stream` may be used for `arr` array and ignore the indexes as in `foreach` loop.

```java
int[] divisors = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(x -> (int) Arrays.stream(arr)
                .filter(y -> x != y && y != 0 && y != 1 && x % y == 0)
                .count()
        )
        .toArray();

int max = Arrays.stream(divisors).max().getAsInt();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(divisors));
System.out.println(max);
```

For test array `int[] arr = {6, 0, 1, 6, 2, 4, 8};` the output is as follows:

```
[1, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
5
```